# How to keep formatting as a Number column in a .csv file?

Tags: excel, csv

I am trying to save an excel file as a .csv file.

A 'Number' formatted column is automatically saved as 'General' column in the .csv file.

I am using Microsoft 2010 version. Is there any way to save all formatting while saving the .csv file from an excel file

Comment: csv doesn't have any meta information, just data.

Comment: But, it contains the 'date' format. Should not it save any other formatting also?

Comment: no it does not. Try opening the csv as a text file you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is wrong:

> A 'Number' formatted column is automatically saved as 'General' column in the .csv file.

Let me explain you, using an example:

In an Excel sheet, I make three columns, called "Name", "Number" and "Date" and fill in the following values:

```
Name   : My_Name 
Number : 12345
Date   : 5/05/2021
```

I save this as CSV file, and this is what I get (the entire file):

```
Name;Number;Date
My_Name;12345;5/05/2021
```

As you see, no formatting is mentioned, just the data itself.

So, CSV is not automatically saved as "General". But when you open a CSV file in an Excel instance, that Excel instance, not knowing anything about the formatting, just automatically applies "General".

Comment: Yes, but, I saved a column specifically using 'Number' and another column as 'Date' format. When I opened the file in excel the 'Date' column is okay, but 'Number' column is showing as 'General'

Comment: @BlackCat That is because, when Excel sees something that looks like a date, in accord with the Windows Regional Settings short-date format, it will interpret it as a date (the same as if you type a date into a cell).  It is not "getting the format" from the csv file.  It is guessing at the format from the nature of the data (and sometimes, it guesses incorrectly).

Comment: I think the question in his comment clarified **exactly** where he was getting hung up in thinking about it. Hopefully my response will enable him to sort that out.